# jQuery: Uploading an image on fileinput.change();

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-io

i have a fileinput control in my html form, which automatically uploads an image to the server once it has been picked up by the user:

```
<input id="uploadedfile" name="uploadedfile" type="file" class="file" />
```

I have attached this event to the **$(document).ready**

```
//uploader event
$('#uploadedfile').change(function(){
    ajaxFileUpload();
});

//upload file
function ajaxFileUpload(){
    $.ajaxFileUpload({
        url:'upload.php',
        secureuri:false,
        fileElementId:'uploadedfile',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data,status){
            if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined'){
                if(data.error){
                    //print error
                    alert(data.error);
                }else{
                    //clear
                    $('#img img').attr('src',url+'cache/'+data.msg);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(data,status,e){
            //print error
            alert(e);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

The **big** problem is that it only works on the first file selection. Any further selections of the fileinput, won't execute the **ajaxFileUpload()** function -- although, if i do replace ajaxFileUpload() with an alert() in the **.change()** event it does work.

**Extra methods for the upload (the error is definitely not here)**

```
jQuery.extend({
    createUploadIframe: function(id,uri){
        var frameId = 'jUploadFrame' + id;
        if(window.ActiveXObject){
            var io = document.createElement('<iframe id="' + frameId + '" name="' + frameId + '" />');
            if(typeof uri== 'boolean') {
                io.src = 'javascript:false';
            } else if(typeof uri== 'string') {
                io.src = uri;
            }
        } else {
            var io = document.createElement('iframe');
            io.id = frameId;
            io.name = frameId;
        }
        io.style.position = 'absolute';
        io.style.top = '-1000px';
        io.style.left = '-1000px';
        document.body.appendChild(io);
        return io
    },
    createUploadForm: function(id,fileElementId){
        var formId = 'jUploadForm' + id;
        var fileId = 'jUploadFile' + id;
        var form = $('<form action="" method="POST" name="' + formId + '" id="' + formId + '" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>');
        var oldElement = $('#' + fileElementId);
        var newElement = $(oldElement).clone();
        $(oldElement).attr('id',fileId);
        $(oldElement).before(newElement);
        $(oldElement).appendTo(form);
        $(form).css('position','absolute');
        $(form).css('top','-1200px');
        $(form).css('left','-1200px');
        $(form).appendTo('body');
        return form;
    },
    ajaxFileUpload: function(s){
        s = jQuery.extend({},jQuery.ajaxSettings,s);
        var id = new Date().getTime();
        var form = jQuery.createUploadForm(id,s.fileElementId);
        var io = jQuery.createUploadIframe(id,s.secureuri);
        var frameId = 'jUploadFrame' + id;
        var formId = 'jUploadForm' + id;
        if(s.global && ! jQuery.active++) {
            jQuery.event.trigger('ajaxStart');
        }
        var requestDone = false;
        var xml = {}
        if(s.global)
            jQuery.event.trigger('ajaxSend',[xml,s]);
        var uploadCallback = function(isTimeout){
            var io = document.getElementById(frameId);
            try {
                if(io.contentWindow) {
                    xml.responseText = io.contentWindow.document.body?io.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML:null;
                    xml.responseXML = io.contentWindow.document.XMLDocument?io.contentWindow.document.XMLDocument:io.contentWindow.document;
                } else if(io.contentDocument) {
                    xml.responseText = io.contentDocument.document.body?io.contentDocument.document.body.innerHTML:null;
                    xml.responseXML = io.contentDocument.document.XMLDocument?io.contentDocument.document.XMLDocument:io.contentDocument.document;
                }
            } catch(e) {
                jQuery.handleError(s,xml,null,e);
            }
            if(xml || isTimeout == 'timeout') {
                requestDone = true;
                var status;
                try {
                    status = isTimeout != 'timeout' ? 'success' : 'error';
                    if(status != 'error') {
                        var data = jQuery.uploadHttpData(xml,s.dataType);
                        if(s.success)
                            s.success(data,status);
                        if(s.global)
                            jQuery.event.trigger('ajaxSuccess',[xml,s]);
                    } else
                        jQuery.handleError(s,xml,status);
                } catch(e) {
                    status = 'error';
                    jQuery.handleError(s,xml,status,e);
                }
                if(s.global)
                    jQuery.event.trigger('ajaxComplete',[xml,s]);
                if(s.global && ! --jQuery.active)
                    jQuery.event.trigger('ajaxStop');
                if(s.complete)
                    s.complete(xml,status);
                jQuery(io).unbind();
                setTimeout(function(){
                    try {
                        $(io).remove();
                        $(form).remove();   
                    } catch(e) {
                        jQuery.handleError(s,xml,null,e);
                    }                                   
                },100);
                xml = null;
            }
        }
        if(s.timeout > 0) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                if(!requestDone) uploadCallback('timeout');
            },s.timeout);
        } try {
            var form = $('#' + formId);
            $(form).attr('action',s.url);
            $(form).attr('method','POST');
            $(form).attr('target',frameId);
            if(form.encoding) {
                form.encoding = 'multipart/form-data';
            } else {
                form.enctype = 'multipart/form-data';
            }
            $(form).submit();
        } catch(e) {
            jQuery.handleError(s,xml,null,e);
        }
        if(window.attachEvent){
            document.getElementById(frameId).attachEvent('onload',uploadCallback);
        } else {
            document.getElementById(frameId).addEventListener('load',uploadCallback,false);
        }
        return {abort: function () {}};
    },
    uploadHttpData: function(r,type) {
        var data = !type;
        data = type == 'xml' || data ? r.responseXML : r.responseText;
        if(type == 'script')
            jQuery.globalEval(data);
        if(type == 'json')
            eval('data = ' + data);
        if(type == 'html')
            jQuery("<div>").html(data).evalScripts();
        return data;
    }
})
```

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the hookup as last entry in the succes and error handler of the $.ajaxFileUpload call in your ajaxFileUpload function and it will work on subsequent clicks.

So it looks like this

```
//uploader event
$('#uploadedfile').change(function(){
  ajaxFileUpload();
});

//upload file
function ajaxFileUpload(){
  $.ajaxFileUpload({
    url:'upload.php',
    secureuri:false,
    fileElementId:'uploadedfile',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data,status){
        if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined'){
            if(data.error){
                //print error
                alert(data.error);
            }else{
                //clear
                $('#img img').attr('src',url+'cache/'+data.msg);
            }
        }
        $('#uploadedfile').change(function(){
          ajaxFileUpload();
        });
    },
    error: function(data,status,e){
        //print error
        alert(e);
        $('#uploadedfile').change(function(){
          ajaxFileUpload();
        });
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

But then again, jQuery.handleError doesn't exist anymore since 1.5

Answer (score 0):

why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?

Use the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)

There is a section about ajax uploads in the examples..

Comment: i'll check it out, but i really need a solution for my current configuration :s

Comment: One day, everyone and anyone that knows about making wheels, will be gone.  Then people will be at a loss because they know how to use wheels, but don't know how to make wheels.